Is it parameter sniffing?
Application uses Entity Framework to create/run query.
SELECT [t].[sbt_assetid], [t].[sbt_messagetimestampmst], [t].[sbt_transid], [t].[CurrentRow], [t].[etl_timestampUTC]
, [t].[sbt_battery], [t].[sbt_cargostate], [t].[sbt_city], [t].[sbt_country], [t].[sbt_extpwr], [t].[sbt_geoname]
, [t].[sbt_geotypename], [t].[sbt_heading], [t].[sbt_idleduration], [t].[sbt_idlegap], [t].[sbt_idlestatus], [t].[sbt_latitude]
, [t].[sbt_longitude], [t].[sbt_messagetype], [t].[sbt_movementstate], [t].[sbt_mtsn], [t].[sbt_quality], [t].[sbt_skyfencestatus]
, [t].[sbt_speed], [t].[sbt_state], [t].[sbt_tetherstate], [t].[sbt_tirestate]
FROM [sb].[TrailerLocations] AS [t]
WHERE ((((((((((((([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_0) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_1) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_2) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_3) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_4) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_5) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_6) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_7) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_8) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_9) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_10) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_11) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))) 
OR (([t].[sbt_assetid] = @__trailerLocation_SbtAssetid_12) AND ([t].[CurrentRow] = 1))

Typically runs < 3 seconds but several times a day exceeds 30 secs whereupon app times out (dev has said need sub 30 sec response times). Table has ~60 million rows. There are 7126 different "assets" that can be passed in as one of 12 parameters .
PK Index on [sbt_assetid] ASC, [sbt_messagetimestampmst] ASC, [sbt_transid], ASC (maybe change sbt_messagetimestampmst to DESC?)
NC Index on [sbt_assetid] ASC, [CurrentRow] DESC
Stats updated automatically (last update yesterday).
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyjnVJcHA

The order of the index doesn't matter for select performance, except maybe to assist in sorting the results.  Is that query plan from when it runs fast or when it runs slow?  Do you have query store turned on?  Do you know which set of parameters were passed in when it went bad?

It seems you've provided the fast execution plan. We'd need to see the slow execution plan. Having your table and index definitions would be helpful too. But TBH your issue is probably all those composite ORs in the WHERE clause.

Since the stats are updating automatically, you’ll want to check the times of the timeouts to exonerate the auto stats updates themselves. You might be getting a few consecutive >30s timeouts while trying to update stats, then one finally succeeds and the rest are ok.

Oh, yeah. If the timeout is occurring while trying to auto-update stats, you won’t be able to provide the "slow plan" via query store or another method. Because the stats updates precede selecting a query plan :-)

Looking at the data you provided, including the execution plan, it is impossible to determine if the attached plan is a parameter sniffing case. I am unsure if any data from your original plan was scrapped while publishing to Brent's site. I even asked a question about missing data, but no answer yet.
I will give you an example with code for identifying parameter sniffing by looking at the execution plan (including XML).
Download WideWorldImporters backup and restore.
USE [WideWorldImporters];
GO

/*
Creating a simple store procedure to select by ContactPersonID
*/

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[OrderID_by_ContactPersonID];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderID_by_ContactPersonID]
    @contactPersonID INT
AS
SELECT 
    OrderID, 
    CustomerID, 
    SalespersonPersonID, 
    ContactPersonID
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE ContactPersonID=@contactPersonID;
GO

/*
Include Actual Execution Plan (CTRL+M)
Look at 'Estimated number of rows' for 'Index Seek' operator 89
*/

EXECUTE [dbo].[OrderID_by_ContactPersonID] @contactPersonID = 1025;
GO

/*
As seen before direct hit for RANGE_HI_KEY  1025
*/

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Sales.Orders', [FK_Sales_Orders_ContactPersonID])
WITH HISTOGRAM;
GO

/*
Include Actual Execution Plan (CTRL+M)
Run the same stored procedure with a different value of 1057
Click to see the properties of the select operator and look at the parameter list, which indicates a parameter sniffing issue.
The plan was compiled with a 1025 value and is now being called with 1057.
Parameter compiled with = 1025 
Parameter runtime value = 1057
*/

EXECUTE [dbo].[OrderID_by_ContactPersonID] @contactPersonID = 1057;
GO


